# Can't install mysql on ubuntu?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, mysql

I've tried several methods, from the terminal and now from the software centre and there I'm getting this error:

```
mysql-client-5.6: Depends: libwrap0 (>= 7.6-4~) but 7.6.q-25 is to be installed
                  Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

How to fix this? What is happening?

Tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-client-core-5.5
0 To upgrade, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B / 702 KB archive.
After this operation, additional 6,969 KB of space used on the drive.
Choose not previously chosen package mysql-client-core-5.5.
(Reading database ... 168860 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to decompress ... / mysql-client-core 5.5_5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpack mysql-client-core-5.5 (5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) ...
Manages triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-2) ...
marko @ marko-VPCEH1L8E: ~ $ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
Some packages could not be installed. It may mean that you have requested
an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution
that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved
from "Incoming".
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have dependencies that can not be satisfied:
 mysql-server: Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it will not be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

It comes more::

```
mysql-client-5.6:
  Installerad: (ingen)
  Kandidat:    5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Versionstabell:
     5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
     5.6.16-1~exp1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
libwrap0:
  Installerad: 7.6.q-25
  Kandidat:    7.6.q-25
  Versionstabell:
 *** 7.6.q-25 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
zlib1g:
  Installerad: 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Kandidat:    1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1
  Versionstabell:
 *** 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Even more::

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 libwrap0 zlib1g
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
libwrap0 is already the newest version.
zlib1g is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. It may mean that you have requested
an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution
that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved
from "Incoming".
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have dependencies that can not be satisfied:
  mysql-client-5.6: Depends: libdbd-mysql-perl (> = 1.2202) but it will not be installed
                     Depends: libdbi-perl but it will not be installed
                     Depends: libterm-ReadKey-perl but it will not be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: sudo apt-get policy mysql-client-5.6 libwrap0 zlib1g
E: Incorrect action policy

Comment: Sorry, start `apt-cache policy mysql-client-5.6 libwrap0 zlib1g`

Comment: And the output of `sudo apt-get install policy mysql-client-5.6 libwrap0 zlib1g`

Comment: sudo apt-get install Policy mysql-client-5.6 libwrap0 zlib1g
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
E: Could not find package policy

Comment: This is really troubling - E: Could not find package policy

Comment: Arg, sorry once again. Without policy please. :\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30502/discussion-between-a-b-and-marko).

Comment: You may set your language to English for copying outputs here by writing `LANG=C` before the command, i.e. `LANG=C sudo apt-get update`. If you type `LANG=C` as only command, the terminal language will be set to English until you close the terminal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system had a hiccup and there are some not upgraded packages.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Now reinstall `perl-base`:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall perl-base
```

But now the problem is:

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
Reinstallation of the perl-base is not possible, it can not be retrieved.
0 upgrade, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Very funny, now we tried this:

```
apt-get download perl-base
```

and, oh no!

```
E: Can't find a source to download version '5.20.1-1' of 'perl-base:amd64'
```

Very, very ... ok, next try:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/perl-base_5.18.2-2ubuntu1_amd6%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B4.deb
```

and **o_O**...

```
--2015-10-20 20:56:05-- mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/…
Resolving mirrors.kernel.org (mirrors.kernel.org)... 149.20.37.36, 198.145.20.143, 2620:3:c000:a:0:1994:3:14, ...
Connecting to mirrors.kernel.org (mirrors.kernel.org)|149.20.37.36|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-10-20 20:56:05 ERROR 404: Not Found.

--2015-10-20 20:56:05-- mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/…
Reusing existing connection to mirrors.kernel.org:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2015-10-20 20:56:05 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Ok, last try, open http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/perl-base/download with your browser and install:

```
sudo dpkg -i perl-base_5.18.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Now we suddenly have a problem with mixed distributions in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. `apt-cache policy …` shows Trusty and `lsb_release -a` and gives the information:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 14.10
Release: 14.10
Codename: utopic
```

Execute:

```
sudo sed -i 's/trusty/utopic/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or delete the file and create a new one using <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd>. After that execute:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And finally...

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

For future readers [here is the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30502/discussion-between-a-b-and-marko).

---

And in the next days, upgrade your system to Wily. Utopic is not supported anymore.

Comment: I found my solution here http://askubuntu.com/questions/720220/apt-not-installing-most-known-packages